# How to extract boolean value out of a Mono<Object> in a non blocking way

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have a validation method which involves **reactive** and **non reactive** objects.

```
private boolean filterByName(String student, Mono<String> teacher) {
      if (student.startsWith("A")) return true; 
       else if(teacher.startsWith("B")) return false; //however teacher is Mono<String> 
}
```

**Question:** How can I return a `boolean` value after successful check of `Mono<String>` without using `block` or `subscribe`

The method which calls `filterByName` is used in another **reactive** method:

```
public Mono<Student> validateStudent(Student student) {
    return Mono.just(student)
        .filter(this::filterByName)
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new Exception("Validation Failed")));
                        
  }
```

Please help me with a way to return a `boolean` successfully without blocking any `Mono`

I am new to Reactive programming. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
  Mono<Boolean> flag = // initialize this;

  flag.flatMap(valie -> {
     if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(value)) {
         return false;
     } else {
        return true;
     }

  })
```

Comment: this doesn't work `no instance(s) of type variable(s) R exist so that Boolean conforms to Mono<? extends R>`